# If i float a h4 and 2 divs to the left and i float 1 div to the right,

Tags: html, css, css-float

If i float a h4 and 2 divs to the left and i float 1 div to the right how do place a block inside the remaining and make it fill the remaining space perfectly. Note! the remaining space needs to have a background colour and i dont want to colour to spread outside this space

[h4][div][div][remaining space][div]

Thanks, regards Tom

Comment: As far as I know, this is impossible without using flexbox, but I might be wrong.

Comment: What you can do here is to put the three divs in a new div with background color and explicitly specify the color of the inner divs to white. This will show the remaining space with the background color of the container div. Or else yu can use tables.

Comment: show us some markup what you've tried or show an image

Comment: @VishalDeep tables is a good idea but unfortunently I cant as my design is responsive

Comment: @flexbox yeah that seems good but i need support without css3 so I guess javascript is only other option?

Comment: Yeah i could mr. alien but you get the basic idea dont you.. Like vishal's solution is good with the background colour explicitcy, but what i actually ment was the have a div fit perfectly in there not spread out. I shouldnt have said colour

Comment: Thanks guys im just gonna go ahead with javascript

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, I think this works?

http://jsfiddle.net/eNDPG/3/